# Handling allocated and stack memory

Tags: c++

I provide two ways to add elements to my collection, once per const reference and once per pointer.

```
void push_back(const value_type *val) {
    element *elem = new element(val);
    //...
}
void push_back(const value_type &val) {
    push_back(&val);
}
```

The `element` class holds the value as a pointer.

```
class element {
private:
    const value_type *value;
public:
    element(const value_type *value):
    value(value) {
    } 

    ~element() {
        delete value;
    }
```

Obviously when elements are popped or the collection is deleted, the memory has to be freed if elements were added as a pointer.
However, this yields an error when the elements were not manually allocated and passed by reference.

Is there any other option to solve this issue than additionally storing if the element is dynamically allocated on push_back time?

Comment: If I understand the code correctly, `push_back(const value_type &)` is just asking for trouble. What if I do this? `{ value_type a; collection.push_back(a); }` The `collection` object will end up holding a dangling pointer once `a` gets destructed at the end of the scope. **This is a terrible design because of that issue already**, and I haven't even talked about the whole "doing very different things whether if the object is on the stack or the heap" thing.

Comment: @Macmade I need to have multiple lists pointing to the same elements and I need to dynamically merge and slice them.

Comment: @Insilico the held variable is not destroyed at the end of the scope.

Comment: I'll grant you that. But this seems to be yet another [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The real problem you seem to be having is having to maintain different lists of the same set of items, which is something [Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/index.html) is designed for.

Comment: This is what happens when you mix allocation idioms in the same container. Just simply don't do it.

Comment: in c++11 there are type traits e.g. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_pointer

Comment: @jev wouldn't that just always return "yes, pointer" for his code since he's pushing the address of the stack-local variable passed in by reference?

Comment: @Insilico The reference push_back was a bad idea in the first place. I'll remove it and let the memory in element handle by shared_ptrs. If that way somehow fails I'll look into Boost, thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just be consistent and always store a pointer that can be deleted.

```
void push_back(const value_type &val) {
    push_back(new value_type(val));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a flawed design in general. And there are different ways you can change your design to achieve what you need. *Mark's answer is a straightforward way to go about it, for example*.

That being said, here is a possible solution using your design. Once again, **I do not recommend it** as it relies on internals of how compilers build stack, and is not portable across compilers/platforms.

Basically, in `~element()` you can check if the address stored in `value` is on stack or on heap by comparing it to the current stack pointer. If the address stored in `value` is higher than the stack pointer then it's on stack and should not be deleted (provided usual location of the stack at top of address space). If it's less than stack pointer - it's on heap.

Code to illustrate the relations of the addresses (GCC, x64 linux):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
 int * heap_(new int(0));
 int stack_(0);
 void * rsp_(nullptr);

 asm("mov %%rsp, %0" : "=m" (rsp_));

 std::cout << "heap address\t: " << heap_ 
           << "\nstack address\t: " << &stack_ 
           << "\nstack pointer\t: " << rsp_ << std::endl;

 delete (heap_);

 return (0);
}
```

Program output:

```
heap address    : 0xc52010
stack address   : 0x7fff528ffee4
stack pointer   : 0x7fff528ffee0
```

ideone.com gives access to GCC, but uses x86 version - `esp` register instead of `rsp`. [The code has to be changed](http://ideone.com/fPqPDH) (non-portability).